# how to install ip_tables and ip6_tables modules in ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.4.0?

Tags: kernel, 18.04, iptables

I'm trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.  I use FireHOL, but FireHOL can't install in 18.04 server, evidently because there are no ip_tables.ko or ip6_tables.ko kernel modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-128-generic.  That is pretty weird, I think.

(I don't know why this installation sticks to the 4.4 kernel when the other 18.04 installations I've done use 4.15.0, and they don't have this problem with missing modules, and FireHOL appears to work fine.  Maybe it's because I kept this host's existing 16.04 mdadm RAID?  I'm going to try starting from bare metal and see what happens.  Very unfortunate to have to recover those terabytes of data from backups.  I hope this isn't the answer.)

Comment: Iptables is installed by default. Is this a custom kernel?  What error do you get exactly? What happens when you run iptables ?

Comment: All stock kernels, as far as I know.  Strictly Ubuntu builds.  (Why create problems for myself?)

Comment: The error occurred during FireHOL installation, and after tracking back through FireHOL's rather beautiful shell scripts, I learned that iptables couldn't run because those modules weren't in the kernel.   And, sure enough, they weren't there.  But it was just a vanilla stock Ubuntu 18.04 server installation -- on an old mdadm RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the existing mdadm RAID, I wiped the RAID superblocks and the partition tables from all 5 disks, and rebuilt the RAID from scratch.  Extremely tedious process, but it worked.  After installation from the alternate-install Ubuntu 18.04 ISO image, I was using kernel 4.15.0 instead of 4.4.0, and 4.15.0 has ip_tables.ko and ip6_tables.ko.  Problem solved, albeit quite tediously.

I can only assume that the existing 16.04 RAID, which may have been even older than 16.04, dating from 14.04 or even 12.04 days (I really don't remember when I built it) could not be supported with a more current mdadm-support module.  That's just a guess.  Anyway, it works now.